# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'progressbar'

Tags: jquery-ui

I wanna use a jQuery UI [Progress Bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/)
Now i am dynamicly creating the progress bar
(I'm creating an uploader simmilar to the one on gmail messages)
And for some reason i get this error.

This is my code:

```
    $('#' + file.id + " b").html('<div id="progressbar"></div>');
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: file.percent
    });
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'progressbar'
```

Anyone has a clue why?

I do have the jQuery UI linked to the file as i'm already using a Dialog on the same page, so that's **NOT** the problem.
Could it be that it messed up because the div does not exist in the intial page loading?

Comment: You may have put the error in your question but I can't see it right now

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean... the error is in the titile

Comment: ah - got ya - the wording "And for some reason i get this error" implies the error message will be display next.  Thanks for clarifying...

Comment: I think you have a custom built jQuery UI, not the entire library, and you are missing the `progressbar` functionality. Verify that you have the `progressbar` in your jQuery UI version. [Your code is OK](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/wxa3E/).

Comment: What does (i) `$("#progressbar").length` (ii) `$("#progressbar")` and (iii) `$.fn.progressbar` give you?

Comment: Ya, Shef was right i did have a custom UI Library i didn't know i need to add progress bar... THanks! write as answer and i'll mark as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Shef's help the problem is solved.
The problem was i had a custom jQuery UI library which didn't include the progressbar.